# R - convert ggplot piechart into plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

I am having trouble trying create the same ggplot pie chart in plotly, as I need plotly's interactive on-hover capability to view the details of a pie chart segment.

It appears plotly will render a gpplot piechart as a bar chart due to the presence of `geom_bar`(my understanding).

I have the following code:

```
g2 <- ggplot( data = DT, aes( x = 1, y = percentage, fill = as.factor( operationtype ) ) ) +
  geom_bar( width = 1, stat = "identity" ) +
  facet_wrap( ~deviceid, ncol = 1 ) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y", start=0) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x  = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y  = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),) + 
  labs( fill = "status" )
plot2 <- ggplotly(g2)
```

Where g2 is the ggplot piechart:
[image]

But after performing  `plot2 <- ggplotly(g2)` , plot2 becomes a bar chart:
[image]

How can render the same pie chart in plotly?

Comment: This is a known issue: https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/878   As a workaround you may create the plot with plotly instead of ggplot2: https://plotly.com/r/pie-charts/

Answer (score 1):

It is best to use `plot_ly` to create the `pie-chart` as shown below:

```
# Create fake data
  df <- data.frame(
    genre=c("Pop", "HipHop", "Latin", "Jazz"), 
    values = c(33,22,25,20)
  )
    
  plot_ly(data=df,labels=~genre, values=~values, type="pie") %>% 
    layout(title = 'United States Music Genre Prevalent in 1999',
           xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
           yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE))
```

[image: output]

Then use `subplot()` to combine multiple plots.